# knockout with-binding leads to "xxx is not a function"

Tags: html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

Hello i have the following code :

```
<ul data-bind="with : weather()" >
    <li>Aktuelles Wetter (15:48)
    <ul>
       <li>
    <span style="float:right;" data-bind="text : weather()" onclick="alert(weatherViewModel.weather().wind.speed);"> km/h </span>
```

I always receive the Error : Typerror : weather is not a function.
The thing is, when I leave the `data-bind="with : weather"` out, I don't get that problem.
I although need the with-binding because I have to access the properties as shown in the `onclick` attribute. 
Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

```
var weatherViewModel = {

weather :  ko.observable(null),

forecast: ko.observable(null)
}
```

Critical part of the ViewModel. The Observable is set via a Ajax-request using kendo-ui as follows:

```
change: function(e) {
    console.debug("weatherDataSource.change");
    console.log("action: " + e.action);
    if (e.action == "sync") {
        console.log("Retrieve weather data...");
        this.read();
    } else {
        var data = this.data();
        console.log(data[0]);
        weatherViewModel.weather(data[0]);
    }
}
```

but this works, since i can acces the data with the onclick-event. The reason i need the with-binding is because the ajax-request is done after the dom element, so i couldn't acces weather().wind.speed, since weather() is null at the beginning.

Comment: Can you post your viewmodel ?

Comment: Sure it's updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "with" binding creates a context, and all bindings inside that context automatically reference the parent context.

So your "text" data binding is failing because there is not a weather function inside weather.